# C++ project Configuration and Linking programmatically

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, include, include-path

I have a project in C++ and we are a team using Visual Studio. The project uses many (really many!) external libraries (boost, armadillo, quantlib, etc).

I am trying to find a way to do the path Configuration and the Linking programmatically through a script and avoid the burden.

So instead of doing the tedious: “right click on Properties -> General-> Additional include directories” or the other tedious: “properties-> Linker-> General-> Additional Libraries Directories”

Instead of doing all the above, I will just add the paths to a script and configure it programmatically.

This will also save time to new joiners in the team.

Any thoughts on how can I achieve this will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using cmake instead of writing your own script that manipulates Visual studio config files?

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I am new to cmake, is this the recommended approach for problems like mine?

Comment: If all the person's involved in the project is going to use visual studio, then I honestly don't see any reason to use another layer of build configuration. What is wrong with configuring include dirs and lib dirs once for each person(only if the paths differ)?

Comment: That there are too many libraries to set up manually and too many new joiners in the team. Ideally, we can build something to automate this process.